# How to do REAL object assignment in JS (shallow copy)

Tags: javascript

In JS, I need to make a shallow copy of an object. It seems that **Object.assign()** is the only option. Is this true, or are there other ways? I would prefer a syntactic method that would do it inside an assignment (that would be an expression rather than a statement). Something to replace `(*1*)`:

```
var a = { x:1978 }; b = a; c = { x:2001 }; [ b ] = [ (*1*) ]
/* I need (a === b) && (b.x === c.x) to hold here */
```

Comment: If you modify the `b,`` [ b ] = [ (*1*) ] `how it could be same as`(a === b)`

Comment: If the intention is to keep `a.x`'s value and have the equality hold, it's not possible. Since `a === b` means `a` and `b` are the same memory ref, updating `b.x` is going to change `a.x`.

Comment: xdeepakv, that's the point of my question: is there a way to do that: modify b's contents (the object b refers to) without modifying the reference. **It can be done** with Object.assign(b, c), but I'm wondering if there is an assignment-like syntax for that.

Comment: marsheth, the intention is to preserve a and b holding the same memory ref, while making the referenced objectc the same as c. As I have mentioned, this can be achieved with Object.assign(b, c) replacing [ b ] = [ (* 1 *) ], but I'd rather use an assignment syntax, if there is any.

Answer (score 1):

There's always [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax), which can be used for objects and other things:

```
b = {...b, ...c}
```

(as an alternative to Object.assign())

Comment: Since @xdeepakv has asked about a === b still being true, I'm assuming that it IS still true because when b.x === c.x, then that implies that a has also gotten a.x with the same value.

Comment: The spread syntax is used inside an object constructor {}, which creates a new object. So after b = {...b, ...c}, b === a won't hold. Unlike Object.assign(b), which would preserve b === a. But thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Good point, @adimetrius! Thank you, and well done.  I completely overlooked that angle. Clearly my suggestion does not fully meet the requirement stated by the OP (that is to say - you).